# How may I properly declare an object array using unique_ptr along with make_unique

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to declare and initialize a `unique_ptr` holding a class array

This is a sample I am using to solve a memory management issue with my project. I can declare the pointer but I am not able to initialize it.

```cpp
class CrewMember
{   
};


class SpaceShip
{

// generates error
std::unique_ptr<CrewMember[3][3]> ship_crew_members = std::make_unique< new CrewMember[3][3]>; 

// compiles fine
std::unique_ptr<CrewMember[3][3]> ship_crew_members;

};
```

errors received:

> call to non-constexpr function 'void* operator new '
>           std::unique_ptr ship_crew_members = std::make_unique< new CrewMember[3][3]>;
>                                                                                                  ^
>   cannot resolve overloaded function 'make_unique' based on conversion to type 'std::unique_ptr'
>           std::unique_ptr ship_crew_members = std::make_unique< new CrewMember[3][3]>;

Comment: `make_unique` is a function template.  You need to do `make_unique<Type>()`.

Comment: `std::make_unique< new CrewMember[3][3]>` 90% sure you can't use `new` in this context.

Comment: Also, it should be something more along the lines of `std::make_unique<CrewMember[3][3]>()`, though I'm not sure this is completely correct.

Comment: @L.F.  and Chipster

I will give that a shot. 
Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Tried this:
```cpp
std::unique_ptr<CrewMember[3][3]> ship_crew_members = std::make_unique< CrewMember[3][3]>();
```
recieved

https://pastebin.com/Kma1Q4S8

Comment: this is what I have currently:
https://hasteb.in/sitapowo.cpp

Comment: Please don't add essential information in comments, comments are for asking for clarification, not for extending your question. Edit the question instead. Also please don't link to external resources, copy everything into the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: That is because my answer had mistakes. I have deleted it, updated it with more correct information, and undeleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `std::unique_ptr` stores a pointer to either a single object, or to a one-dimensional array. Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported. It can theoretically store a pointer to a multidimensional array, if you do an evil cast, but you really should not.
2. If you really want to use `std::unique_ptr` to store a multidimensional array, you'd need to do some extra work and use a one-dimensional array and then calculate the offset for the multidimensional index yourself (e.g. `[1][2]` becomes `1*3+2`).
3. `std::make_unique` is a function template. The template parameter needs to be a proper type, which either is a class or a class array (but without the size). If your type is an array and you give `std::make_unique` a size as parameter, it will create a `std::shared_ptr` that points to an array of that size and uses the proper `delete[]` operator on that array when it gets destructed.

All together that would look something like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<CrewMember[]> ship_crew_members = std::make_shared<CrewMember[]>(9);
```

However I strongly advice against doing this. Much simpler is to use any of the std containers, e.g. `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CrewMember>> ship_crew_members;
```

This gives you a multidimensional container of varying size, that you can add elements to or remove elements from.

Or `std::array` for a fixed size multidimensional array:

```
std::array<std::array<CrewMember, 3>, 3> ship_crew_members;
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxVollmer you helped me greatly!

I will implement the code and explanation you have given me, into my project!